# Is it possible to access void * pointers that point to different types when parsing through void *?

Tags: c, parsing, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = "hi";
    char *str2 = "bye";
    size_t size = 2;
    size_t size2 = 3;
    size_t zero = 0;
    void *pack;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++, pack++, str++ ){
        pack = str;
    }

    pack = &size;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);
    pack = &size2;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);
    pack = &zero;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);

    for(int i= 0; i < size2; i++, pack++, str2++){
        pack = str2;
    }  
}
```

I'm wondering if I were to call a function that used "pack" would it be in the form, [char, char, size_t, size_t, size_t, char, char, char].

I've tried starting at the beginning of pack and parsing through it using "pack++" and the addresses of my size_t variables are not there. Would the size_t variables be there if I were to have a function to unpack the "pack" variable? It does not seem to work in the main function. If not how would I be able to access the size_t variables when parsing through "pack". And before you ask, I have to use a void pointer for a project.

Comment: you can't do pointer arithmetic on a `void*` pointer. Pointer arithmetic needs to know the size of the type it points to, and `void*` doesn't point to any particular type.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, so it's meaningless to ask what the variable will point to as a result.

Comment: What's the point of the first `for` loop? You immediately reassign `pack` after it's done.

Comment: `void*` pointers don't know anything about the type of size of whatever they point to. Before you can do anything useful with it, you have to cast it to a pointer to the actual type. It's just used as a way to pass pointers through a generic intermediary (look at how it's used in `qsort()`, for instance).

Comment: @Barmar I'm 100% with you, but "This code shouldn't even compile" is something I've realized is risky to say when C is in focus. Apparently C can be whatever the implementors want it to be - even though the standard is what it is. I've tried to find a way of saying that _"a compiler only accepting code adhering to the strictest letter of the standard..."_ - ... but I never land in something reusable. Holes are poked into that too :-D

Comment: ... but, a `void*` can be thought of a pointer to an element of indeterminate size. You can't add or subtract to it - since, well, how far should the compiler step the pointer?

Comment: @Barmar: [The code compiles.](https://godbolt.org/z/asodzP3TE) You can do pointer arithmetic on a `void *` pointer, if the compiler defines it, which [GCC does](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith). There is a difference between things the C standard does not define (plenty) and things that are forbidden (very little) or that you cannot do.

Comment: @EricPostpischil :-) My comment above was exactly to what you just demonstrated. As a thought experiment, I thought to myself that I could just use scripting languages  and invent types on the fly and who'd care? ... well, that's me. I realize that the intentional implementation points in the C standard doesn't make it into a standard at all. It's just something to work with. Back in the day, we called it Basic. It had a new flavour every month. ... and adding meaning to `void*` arithmenthics **can't** be anything but lazy?! Why have types? _"Today a `void*` points at elements of size 0"_ ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo: One reason `void *` arithmetic might have been added to GCC was to support kernel code, which often needs to work with addresses on behalf of user processes but should not normally dereference it, at least not without some care. Defining `void *` arithmetic fits that; it makes it easy for the kernel to do various calculations with the addresses but would give an error if kernel code accidentally dereferenced an address.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's a necessity bleed and/or lack of wanting to add a fundamental type then? I don't think the `non_dereferencable_address_pointer_with_byte_size_arithmetics` type I have in mind will get much tracktion but ... still. I'd use it when I need it, which isn't often.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Casting the pointer to `char*` so you can do arithmetic doesn't dereference it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And you're right, I forgot that GCC implements `void*` arithmetic simply it by treating it as `char*`.

Comment: For the purpose of learning C programming, then don't have GNU extensions enabled... GNU considered harmful. Instead force the compiler to use strict ISO C with max warnings enabled: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 1):

The statement `pack = str;` assigns the value of `str` to the object `pack`. `str` is a pointer, and its initial value is the address of the “h” of `"hi"`. So `pack = str;` sets `pack` to point to the “h” of `"hi"`.

You apparently want to set the byte that `pack` points to to the byte that `str` points to. To access the byte (or other object) that a pointer points to, you must *dereference* the pointer, which can be done using the unary `*` operator.

However, since the type of `pack` is `void *`, the compiler would not know what type you want to access if you wrote `*pack`. So you must convert the pointer to the type you want to use. To copy bytes using the `char` type, you would convert the pointer to `char *` and then dereference it:

```
* (char *) pack = *str;
```

Similarly, in the second loop, you need `* (char *) pack = str2;`.

However, before you do that, you need to make `pack` point to somewhere. You have `void *pack;`, which leaves `pack` uninitialized. You should set it to point to memory where the bytes are to be written.

These statements:

```
    pack = &size;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);
    pack = &size2;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);
    pack = &zero;
    pack += sizeof(size_t);
```

repeatedly set `pack` to various addresses and then adjust it. This is not useful, as only the last value will remain. The prior values have no effect. Again, to do anything useful in the loop that follows this code, you must set `pack` to point to suitable memory.

Doing the above might get the program working in GCC or Clang, because these compilers define arithmetic on `void *` to work in units of bytes (character objects). To be portable to other C implementations, you need to define `pack` to be `char *` instead of `void *`, or you need to change the arithmetic expressions to use casts so that the arithmetic is done with `char *` instead of `void *`.